# Logic behind Android Studio lint warning on 'findViewById' returning null

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm curious about the logic behind lint warning on `NullPointerException`.

I noticed it sometimes warns me on the **first usage** of a `View` after `findViewById`, perhaps thinking maybe the layout.xml doesn't have the ID, but other times it won't warn. I never paid too much attention and always ignored this warning.

Today, something more weird happened... Apparently the order of statements also matter? That led me thinking maybe there's something more to it. Maybe I shouldn't ignore these warnings?

[image]

Comment: While using `RecyclerView` you must always set a layout. As by default `RecyclerView` is a space where you can add layout dynamically. If the type of space is not set, then there is no any space which might cause `NullPointerException`.